# EWS Managed API 1.1 - Pull Subscriptions Memory Leak

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Has anyone else discovered a memory leak issue with Pull Subscriptions (`ExchangeService.SubscribeToPullNotifications()`) in [Exchange Managed Web Services API](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480)? When calling `PullSubscription.GetEvents()` the memory utilization climbs 4K with nearly every polling call. The only way I've been able to keep the memory utilization down is by forcing garbage collection (via `GC.Collect()`) after every call - an unnecessary path.

I am surprised to see the API hasn't changed for almost a year.

Comment: Keep on doing the GC.Collect() - it is Ok as the Exchange API call masks the time used by the garbage collector. It is quite possible that you have a leak in your code however.

Comment: I ruled out the code leak by creating a simple console app that only creates a single subscription and polls it in a `while(true)` after 5 seconds of delay. However - the memory keeps climbing (especially when you have multiple subscriptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891283/how-to-force-garbage-collection-of-object-you-cant-dereference). Essentially EWS was conflicting with another component that failed to release a `NetworkStream` (due to a `SqlException`). [ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) was used to pinpoint the cause and timing of the issue. Without this profiling tool we would have never discovered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if a GC.Collect reclaims the memory, there is no memory leak. There is just not pressure on the GC to perform a GC collection, since enough memory is available.